# Add path to Includes

Tags: c, eclipse

I'm making C application In Eclipse under Ubuntu. In Project Explorer I see section Includes that contains several include paths. How to add my custom directory to Includes?

Answer (score 0):

In `Project Explorer` right click on the project and select `Properties`. From there you can go to `C/C++ General -> Path and Symbols`.

here you can customize various settings for your project, among other things the include path.